# How can I trace Win32 window-messages on Windows 7?

Tags: winapi, etw

Lately I've been tracing Win32 Window Messages using ETW (`logman`, `xperf`, WPA, et cetera) which is relatively straightforward because the `Microsoft-Windows-Win32k` provider exports ETW events for `SendMessage`, `TranslateMessage`, `DispatchMessage`, etc.

...but today I needed to perform a similar trace on a Windows 7 SP1 machine, and to my surprise the Windows 7 version of the `Microsoft-Windows-Win32k` provider [is very anemic](https://github.com/repnz/etw-providers-docs/blob/master/Manifests-Win7-7600/Microsoft-Windows-Win32k.xml) - it only exposes coarser-level events - and reports errors in window-message processing (e.g. `UIPIMsgError`), but not window-messages themselves.

After some quick-research, apparently `Microsoft-Windows-Win32k` didn't surface Window Messages events until [Windows 10's first release in 2015](https://github.com/repnz/etw-providers-docs/blob/master/Manifests-Win10-10240/Microsoft-Windows-Win32k.xml), meaning it wasn't possible to use ETW to capture this information in Windows 8.1, Windows 7, Vista or XP.

...but collecting that data is essential for many kinds of debugging and troubleshooting tasks. For trivial or smaller troubleshooting situations we have Spy++ which reports all window-messages received by any other window (and I'm already familiar [with how Spy++ works](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/spy-internals/) internally) but that makes Spy++ unsuitable for large-scale dragnet-style traces of Window Messages, not to mention how Spy++ doesn't timestamp Window Messages with high-precision timestamps either.

---

**So...** just how did performance-engineers or troubleshooters doing causality analysis accurately bulk-record Window Messages prior to Windows 10?

Comment: Since you know how Spy++ works, you also know how to capture a trace of window messages. I don't understand why the standard message timestamps were insufficient. They are as precise a measure of message generation as there is.

Comment: @IInspectable They’re nowhere near as precise as QPC, and automating Spy++ would require writing a lot of code - the tooling just isn’t there

Comment: QPC provides higher resolution but doesn't grant you more precision. The `time` field of the [`MSG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msg) structure is as accurate as you get. I doubt that writing a message tracer comes down to *"writing a lot of code"*. It's just three hooks plus an MPSC channel. If you are looking for a pre-built tool, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks - I had completely overlooked the `MSG.time` field, erk

Comment: but MSG.time is only logged for posted messages. I also find Spy++ and its lack of time stamps very hard to use if I need to correlate user hangs with the logged spy messages.